# Should i use useReducer hook when every action is calling api?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand the `useReducer` hooks and when to use `it`. From what i learnt when there is complex data and lots of function to update data in the component i should use `use Reducer` rather than storing data in `useState` hook

Here my current code so far

```
const ACTIONS = {
  INCREMENT: 'increment',
  DECREMENT: 'decrement',
  RESET: 'reset',
  CHANGE_COUNT: 'change-count'
}

function reducer(count, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.INCREMENT:
      return count + 1
    case ACTIONS.DECREMENT:
      return count - 1
    case ACTIONS.RESET:
      return 0
    case ACTIONS.CHANGE_COUNT:
      return count + action.payload.amount
    default:
      return count
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [count, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, 0)

  return (
    <>
      <span>{count}</span>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.INCREMENT })}>
        +
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.DECREMENT })}>
        -
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => {
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.CHANGE_COUNT,
          payload: { amount: 5 }
        })
      }}>
        Add 5
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.RESET })}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

So I can control all the local_state in the component.

But Imagine if count data is coming back from server and every actions need to `call an api` back to `backend` server to update the data. I don't think i can still pass around only `dispatch` to other components.

So in that case should i still try to use `useReducer hook` and `pass dispatch only` or **write a function for each kind of update and passed around**?

Comment: You are looking into it, IMO, in a complex way. redux is not much different then `useState` in what they achieve - a state that once updated will re render the component with new data. The main difference is that `useState` is a hook that creates a local state for a single component. while Redux state is global - its ment for the entire project. The reason it was created is to prevent important data to be passed around as props from parents to children. SO if the data you require is used in other components - store it with redux. if the data is for parent and 1 2 children - use local state.

Comment: @Lith I am not referring to redux. I am referring to useReducer hook.